# Rank function is not giving the number "1" to the lowest value

Tags: r, rank

I am taking a set of data and attempting to retrieve the lowest value. I believe that the easiest way to do this is by using the rank function followed by the which function to retrieve the lowest value's index.

I'm new so I'm not really sure what else to try, but when I rank the data, it does not rank it properly so that the lowest value is assigned the value of 1.

```
name_data <- data[2]

state_data <- data[7]

heart_failure_data <- data[17]

heart_failure_data[heart_failure_data == "Not Available"] <- NA

# Remove NA values
full_data<-heart_failure_data[complete.cases(heart_failure_data),]

full_state<-state_data[complete.cases(heart_failure_data),]

# Only rank data from the given state
data_by_state <- full_data[full_state==state]

ranking <- rank(data_by_state, ties.method = "first")

top_index <- which(ranking == 1)

name_by_state <- name_data[state_data==state,1]

name_by_state[top_index]
```

For this particular data set, when I read the data, the 42nd value is the lowest (8.1), but the rank function assigns the value 1 to the 71st number (value 10.1). Why is that? Thanks in advance.

Edit: Thanks for the help! As Rui Barradas suggested, my data frame essentially contained the characters of the number (ie "13.1" vice 13.1) which prevented the ranking function from working properly. I used as.numeric(as.character()) to convert the data and I got the expected response.

Comment: Just read the first few lines, but take a look at `?which.min`. Edit: read a few more, but you should add a reproducible example, otherwise it might be difficult to figure out what's going on.

Comment: `data` seems to be a data.frame. If so, `data[2]`, `data[7]` and `data[17]` are also of class `"data.frame"`. And what you probably have is ranks of something else than numbers. What is `str(data_by_state)` outputting?